# <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z' with lambda and reduce

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, functional-programming, reduce

I was trying to understand how `lambda` and `reduce()` works. I tried these examples but not able to understand why this is giving me the error. Can someone please explain how it is being executed?

```
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, range(10))
45
```

This works fine. But when I tried this, It gives me error:

```
>>> functools.reduce(lambda x,y,z:x+y+z, range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'z'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`functools.reduce` requires a function of two arguments.
You cannot pass a `lambda x, y, z` as the function because that's a function of 3 arguments.
(In Python it's an error to call a function with incorrect number of arguments. `functools.reduce` would call the `lambda x, y, z` with only 2 arguments instead of 3, and so that's an error.)

From `help(functools.reduce)`:

> ```
> reduce(...)
>     reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value
>
>     Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
>     from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
>     For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
>     ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).
> ```